# Comparar as distancias do top de um elemento com o seguinte next()

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou recebendo o seguinte erro no console:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined

Ele está dizendo que o erro ocorre na seguinte linha:

```
alturaproximo = $(this).next().offset().top;
```

Segue o código:

```
$('.lego').each(function() {
    var alturadesse = $(this).offset().top,
        alturaproximo = $(this).next().offset().top;
        console.log(alturadesse);

    var zindex = 5;
    if ( alturadesse == alturaproximo ) {
        $(this).css({'z-index': zindex});
    } if ( alturadesse > alturaproximo ) {
        zindex + 1;
        $(this).css({'z-index': zindex});
    }
});
```

Acredito que ele não está conseguindo pegar a altura `offset().top` por causa do `next()`.
Alguém saberia o que eu preciso fazer para comparar as distancias do top de um elemento e do próximo elemento igual a ele?

Comment: Não é no final quando chega no ultimo e não tem um próximo?

Comment: Cara, era isso mesmo!! Hahaha. Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Conforme respondido no comentário, o problema era quando chegava no ultimo elemento e não existia o próximo `.next()` causando o erro.

Por favor edite esta reposta e inclua o código corrigido aqui, para a pergunta sair da lista de sem respostas...